# How do I select a desired row in a grouped result using c# LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Customer table like this

```
ID EndDate 
1  2/11/2010
1  3/14/2011
2  5/3/2011
2  12/1/2011
3  4/5/2010
```

I want to take the maximum date's row for each ID group
the result like this:

```
ID EndDate
1  3/14/2011
2  12/1/2011
3  4/5/2010
```

How do I use one fluent syntax in c# (without looping or 2nd statement) to get the result back?

```
Customers.GroupBy( c => c.ID ).....//How do I proceed?
```

Comment: Sorry I do not know how to format the  Customer Table in a tabular form in here... someone please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
var results = Customers.GroupBy(c => c.ID)
                       .Select(
                          g => g.OrderByDescending(c => c.EndDate).First() );
```

Comment: If the table truly only contains the two columns, then you can just use Max instead of the orderby and First... see my answer below.

Comment: @ach Max would return the DateTime, not the Customer object.  You can't use Max in this situation.  You could do it with MoreLinq's MaxBy or something similar, but not the BCL classes.  See: http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs